# How do I export a Google Drive file using the Java SDK

Tags: java, google-drive-api

The listed solutions on the page linked below do not cover this topic: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads

Answer (score 0):

I got this piece of code after some try and error:

```
String odt = file.getExportLinks().get("application/pdf");
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:/data/test_" + file.getTitle() + ".pdf")) {
    service.files().get(file.getId()).getMediaHttpDownloader().download(new GenericUrl(odt), fos);
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

And here are two alternatives:

```
public static InputStream download(Drive service, String url) throws IOException {
    return service.getRequestFactory().buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(url)).execute().getContent();
}

public static void download(Drive service, String url, OutputStream os) throws IOException {
    HttpRequestFactory rf = service.getRequestFactory();
    new MediaHttpDownloader(rf.getTransport(), rf.getInitializer()).download(new GenericUrl(url), os);
}
```

But I do wonder if there is even more idiomatic way to get a MediaHttpDownloader.

PS: I think the proper way should be added to the Google documentation page.